# IE undefined Javascript & CSS Error

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

So IE is throwing back an error for two of my scripts on my site. Attached!

[image]

Can anyone identify why this may be happening and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: `swfobject` is a flash object, do you have flash installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include swfobject.js or you did not link to it properly. The same goes for ddsmoothmenu.js. What I see is that you use `js/file.js` instead of `/js/file.js`.

Comment: Either one of those URLs may work, depending on the file structure.

Comment: Yeah, this assumes a lot about his file structure, js/ might work and /js could break it too.

Comment: tried both /js/file.js and js/file.js - neither seem to have an effect

Comment: the issue related to the source

Answer (score 0):

Hope this fix helps others who stumble upon the same problem

for "ddsmppthmenu.js" code fix below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ddsmppthmenu.js">
    ddsmoothmenu.init({
      mainmenuid: "tempo_menu", //menu DIV id
      orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
      classname: 'ddsmoothmenu', //class added to menu's outer DIV
      //customtheme: ["#1c5a80", "#18374a"],
      contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
 })
 </script>
```